# How to create conditional build properties in DevOps build pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-devops-pipelines

I have the following build pipeline task:

```
  - task: NuGetCommand@2
    displayName: 'Pack CodingStyles.nuspec'
    inputs:
      command: 'pack'
      packagesToPack: 'src\CodingStyles\CodingStyles.nuspec'
      packDestination: 'src\CodingStyles\bin'
      versioningScheme: 'off'
      buildProperties: '-NoDefaultExcludes -Version $(Build_Major).$(Build_Minor).$(Build_Patch)'
```

However, if the variable `$IsPreRelease` is true, I want to add another build property as well:

```
buildProperties: '-NoDefaultExcludes -Version $(Build_Major).$(Build_Minor).$(Build_Patch) -Suffix beta'
```

A few thoughts on how to do this:

1. I could have two different versions of this task, each with a `condition:` based on the variable.  This would probably work, but it's quite redundant since everything else is the same.
2. Run a Powershell task instead of the NuGetCommand task, and build my command line dynamically.

Any options I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You are missing one option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#conditionally-set-a-task-input):

```yaml
  - task: NuGetCommand@2
    displayName: 'Pack CodingStyles.nuspec'
    inputs:
      command: 'pack'
      packagesToPack: 'src\CodingStyles\CodingStyles.nuspec'
      packDestination: 'src\CodingStyles\bin'
      versioningScheme: 'off'
      ${{ if ne(variables['IsPreRelease'], 'true') }}:
        buildProperties: '-NoDefaultExcludes -Version $(Build_Major).$(Build_Minor).$(Build_Patch)'
      ${{ if eq(variables['IsPreRelease'], 'true') }}:
        buildProperties: '-NoDefaultExcludes -Version $(Build_Major).$(Build_Minor).$(Build_Patch) -Suffix beta'
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately DevOps doesn't let you repeat the same key twice..

Comment: Are you sure? I checked and you can save and run this. I notice some highlighting mentioning about duplication but this is display issue. All is fine with this snippet.

Comment: Oh if it's just a display error which I can ignore, then we should be good.. I'll try it out!